# Pyspark save data frame as csv with many vector columns

Tags: csv, vector, pyspark, export-to-csv, one-hot-encoding

I have a pyspark data frame with hundreds of columns that are one-hot encoded (in vector format).

I need to save this data frame, but I can’t save it to a csv since csv doesn’t accept vector formatted columns.

What is the best way to save this data frame? Should I loop over all columns and convert them to strings and then save as csv?